# Powershell rename files

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I need to rename over 1000 files with Powershell but need help as I am not that familiar with the tool...tried already many codes but they didn't work :-(

Here some example files:

342453-gggssd - Mike Oldfield
ggiuk_3245435sss - Melissa Black
File-435435-23423 - Tom Hanks

I want to keep only the employee name

Mike Oldfield
Melissa Black
Tom Hanks

There are pdf, jpeg, docx, png files. All files are in one folder.
Could someone help me with this?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: https://superuser.com/search?q=powershell+rename

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SuperUser. We're not a "Please write me a script" kind of service. Show us the script you developed so far and we can help you find out why things are not working correctly.

Comment: Google "Bulk Rename Utility"

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your sample filenames, it appears to me that the one constant is that the employee name is separated from any preceeding text by `<space>-.space>`. Targeting that sequence will prevent confusion with hyphens in the "prefix" sequence as well as allow for hyphenated last names. So this is a simple exercise in string manipulation. The hardest part is choosing which method you want to use! Here are two options you can copy & paste to see it in action:

- The [-Split](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#replacement-operator) operator:

  - `('342453-gggssd - Mike Oldfield' -split ' - ')[-1]`
- The [-Replace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#replacement-operator) operator:

  - `'342453-gggssd - Mike Oldfield' -replace '^.+ - '`

You'll want to perform this operation against the Basename of each file and combine it with the existing extension to construct the new name:

```
$SourceDir = 'c:\Path\To\Source\Folder'
Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceDir -File | Rename-Item -NewName { ( $_.BaseName -replace '^.+ - ' ) + $_.Extension }
```

Thats the verbose version, which you should use when writing scripts. As you become proficient and familiar with aliases and positional parameters, it could be shortened to this when working interactively at the console:

```
gci $SourceDir -af | ren -new { ( $_.BaseName -replace '^.+ - ' ) + $_.Extension }
```

Comment: I don't consider turning someone on to **PowerShell** with a simple real-life example as providing a "script writing service". Anytime you can steer someone away from batch toward PowerShell, you're doing God's work! :D